# Nuxt equivalent of Vue Route Guards 'Next'

Tags: nuxt.js

In Vue we have access to the following parameters in our `beforeRouteEnter` property:

```
async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    //Code here
    next();
},
```

How can I use `next()` or an equivalent in Nuxt's middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to find an equivalent, but it seems we can ignore the need for `next()` and just return, and Nuxt will continue naturally to the next page.